What writing system are they using in "Yu-Gi-Oh!"?
What language or writing system are some of these cards using in Yu-Gi-Oh!?
For Example:

Spellbinding Circle


Seal of Orichalcos


Rank-Up-Magic Escape Force


Phantom Knight's Spear


Megamorph


Ichiroku's Ledger Book


Dark Contract with Errors


Admiration of the Keepers



Are they just made up languages and writing systems or are they based off of any existing languages and writing systems?
I believe the symbols on the "Seal of Orichalcos" are called Enochian Alphabet if I'm not mistaken. But I don't know the others on the rest of the cards.
